# Javascript: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null Dynamically created <div> MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a table from entries in my model.

I have a foreach which has the following code for each item:

```
<td class="answerTD">
    <div class="answerOptionDiv" onclick="rightanswer(A1@(item.id))">
         @item.Choice1
    </div>
</td>
<td class="answerTD">
    <div id="A1@(item.id)" class="rightAnswer">Correct</div>
</td>
```

I am using the item id along with an alpabetical range to provide unique names for each div

I have a very simple javascript function (which works on another form which is not dynamically created) which simply shows the answer div:

```
<script>
    function rightanswer(x) {
        console.info = 'Fired Right';
        document.getElementById(x).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

When I test the function in Firebug I get the following error and the console does not show my info message:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

document.getElementById(x).style.display = 'block';
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass arguments in quotes.

Use

```
<div class="answerOptionDiv" onclick="rightanswer('A1@(item.id)')">
```

instead of

```
<div class="answerOptionDiv" onclick="rightanswer(A1@(item.id))">
```

Comment: whilst fooling around getting the id from the model I somehow lost my quotes .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

if something is created dynamically in jQuery, and you want to catch the calls, you have to make sure you place the functions right next to each other. Say you want to show a button through a .click function, and you want to use a .click on the second button. You must make sure you place those in the same function, otherwise it won't be able to call it.

this will not work:

```
$("#buttonOne").click(function() { 
   $("#divId").append("<a id='buttonTwo'>simpleButton</a>");
});
$("#buttonTwo").click(function() { alert("clicked"); });
```

but this will:

```
$("#buttonOne").click(function() { 
   $("#divId").append("<a id='buttonTwo'>simpleButton</a>");
   $("#buttonTwo").click(function() { alert("clicked"); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm new 2 Stackoverflow

In asp.net Actualy Startup is my id but on clientside it will be displayed as ctl00_dmrcontent_Startup so in ur script change onclick="rightanswer('A1@(item.id)')" then check div id displayed in clientside

```
<div  id="Startup" runat="server">
```